# VB6 connecting to Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, vb6

We have a program written in VB6 that in the past connected to Oracle 9. Now we have some new computers with windows 7 on them, so we had to install oracle 11g to be compatible.

But now our program can't connect to the database anymore. Other stuff like sql*Plus connects fine.
Is there something we have to change in the program to get it to work or is there an extra driver we have to install,...?

Comment: There was an Oracle supplied ODBC driver - it has to be licensed.

Comment: @jim, Oracle client software (including ODBC driver) is free.

Comment: My company licenses by seat.....  FWIW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check - does your VB6 app have a binary dependency on the Oracle 9 `OCI.DLL`? If so, it's probably looking for it and failing. Might be worth a recompile for Win7 clients to pick-up the new library. What error do you see when the app fails?

Comment: i wish there were more feedback on this issue... That'd be really helpful